# How to input commands on the Live CD mode selection screen

Tags: boot, login-screen

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-fix-ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid-blank-screen-at-startup.html

I have the problem in the above answer page and to fix it I need to highlight Live Mode on the CD/USB and press F6 and then type a command. However when I press F6 I get a selection of options.

So how do you input commands on the Live CD mode-selection screen as suggested in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

Press F6, then Escape. It should drop down to something like this:

[image]

You can then proceed to add options, as shown on the screenshot. The input will already be focused on that text field. To boot, hit Enter.