# Monitor Display issue

Tags: nvidia, resolution, screen

When booting I will have to boot maybe 3 or 4 times to get a screen that is not displayed diagonally or is not using the full screen width.

**Hardware specification:**  HP s7727c with AMD64 and NVIDIA chipsets and Insignia 22" monitor/TV.  The Ubuntu version is 9.10 Karmic.

I'd like to stay current with Ubuntu on this machine, but have gone down to 9.10 to get this described functioning.  I tried higher versions and could not get past the "black screen"  I think this issue is connected to the NVIDIA chipset/driver problem.

I am a GUI user and I don't follow the other solutions posted which make use of the command line.  I suppose if the command line solution could be given without making any assumptions of the receiving person's knowledge base, then even I and others like me, could implement it.

Thank you for your time and assistance.  Doug

Answer (score 1):

Doug - you may be aware that 9.10 is no longer supported and you will no longer get any updates nor will be able to install up-to-date software from the repositories.

As to your black-screen issues on either the installation of 10.04 or higher, maybe my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41600/ubuntu-11-04-wont-install-at-all/41626#41626) should help.

Possibly your nvidia issues could be solved using my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834)