# How do you edit the Blacklist.conf file?

Tags: lubuntu, live-cd

Is it possible to edit the Blacklist.conf file when running Linux off a Live CD? If so, how do you edit it?

I tried typing this into the terminal but nothing happened:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Comment: The problem here is that because (according to this question's tagging) you're running Lubuntu, the preinstalled text editor is `leafpad`, but you're trying to edit the file with `gedit` (preinstalled in regular Ubuntu systems and live CD's). That's the *cause* of the problem. [Elfy's answer explains how to fix your problem (by running `leafpad` instead).](http://askubuntu.com/a/148640/22949)

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to have the files for the system you want to edit mounted.

Look in the left panel for the file system in pcmanfm (the file manager) and click on it - it will look 'similar' to this

[image]

You can see that I have mounted my 12.10 partition

Check what the path is called for you - could be /media/long UUID reference and then run

```
gksudo leafpad /media/longUUIDreference/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

from a terminal.

Comment: what if it isn't mounted?  How would I mount it?

Comment: Click on that drive in pcmanfm - it should be in the left panel, my 12.10 wasn't mounted until I clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to prevent a certain module from loading at boot time ("blacklisting"), you could append the boot option `modprobe.blacklist=<module-name>`. E.g., to prevent `nouveau` from loading, you'd use `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau`.

To do so on an installation, see [How do I add a kernel boot parameter?](https://askubuntu.com/q/19486/6969). For a Live CD/USB, see [How to input commands on the Live CD mode selection screen](https://askubuntu.com/q/5609/6969) (I believe that you need to press a different key first in newer versions, e.g. <kbd>Space</kbd>).

Comment: well what I am trying to do is get my wireless network to work and someone told me to add the following to the blacklist.conf file:   

"blacklist padlock_aes" and "blacklist geode_aes"  

So would I be able to do that?

Comment: In other words, what should I type exactly?

Comment: Try `modprobe.blacklist=padlock_aes,geode_aes` (actually, it should not matter whether you use `padlock_aes` or `padlock-aes` as name).