# ubuntu server: network precedence (wired before wifi)

Tags: wireless, networking, server, network-manager

I'm running Ubuntu Server 14.04, and have both "auto wlan0" and "auto p4p1" in my /etc/network/interfaces file as I have both a wifi card and a network port (described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541247/ubuntu-server-wifi)).  I want the computer to use the wired connection, but fall back on the wifi if the network cable is not plugged in.

Currently, both connections are "on" whenever I boot up.  How can I make wifi to not be on when a network cable is plugged in, and turned on when a network cable is unplugged?  That is, I'd like to have the network connections be 'smart' like in Ubuntu desktop.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

go to network manager and delete both the wired and wifi connections.  reboot.  it will find both the wifi and wired connections the next time it starts up.  make one of the the connections the "prefered connection".  you can't "flip" back and forth between wifi/wired with ubuntu.  it won't "fallback".  why you ask are you having network compatibily issues?

Comment: Network manager? What is that? I think you are describing Ubuntu desktop. I'm working on Ubuntu server, which has no GUI. Thanks.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/148631/how-do-you-edit-the-blacklist-conf-file