# Problem with USB device (UPEK Fingerprint reader)

Tags: 16.04

I am sort of a novice but am decently familiar with linux, but this one is giving me a headache.  My thinkpad has an integrated UPEK fingerprint reader.  Looking at it, it appears that is like disconnecting and reconnecting repeatedly.  While I would like it to work, I'd be fine with just making it stop doing whatever it is doing.

From lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 100: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor

Bus 001 Device 116: ID 147e:2016 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
```

every time I check lsusb its either not shown or has a different device number

dmesg is more distressing to my calm.

```
[ 1165.456828] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 102 using ehci-pci
[ 1165.952794] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 102, error -32
[ 1166.448652] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 103 using ehci-pci
[ 1166.561577] usb 1-1.3: device descriptor read/all, error -32
[ 1166.568653] usb 1-1-port3: attempt power cycle
[ 1167.380700] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 104 using ehci-pci
[ 1167.418440] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=147e, idProduct=2016
[ 1167.418447] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1167.418451] usb 1-1.3: Product: Biometric Coprocessor
[ 1167.418455] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: UPEK
[ 1167.792954] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 104
[ 1168.016572] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 105 using ehci-pci
[ 1168.512634] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 105, error -32
[ 1169.008614] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 106 using ehci-pci
[ 1169.504492] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 106, error -32
[ 1169.504558] usb 1-1-port3: attempt power cycle
[ 1170.108542] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 107 using ehci-pci
[ 1170.524441] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 107, error -32
[ 1171.020494] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 108 using ehci-pci
[ 1171.057804] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=147e, idProduct=2016
[ 1171.057809] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1171.057813] usb 1-1.3: Product: Biometric Coprocessor
[ 1171.057815] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: UPEK
[ 1171.376909] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 108
[ 1171.604358] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 109 using ehci-pci
[ 1172.104333] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 109, error -32
[ 1172.604362] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 110 using ehci-pci
[ 1173.100326] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 110, error -32
[ 1173.100452] usb 1-1-port3: attempt power cycle
[ 1173.704275] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 111 using ehci-pci
[ 1174.120322] usb 1-1.3: device not accepting address 111, error -32
[ 1174.616182] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 112 using ehci-pci
[ 1174.653942] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=147e, idProduct=2016
[ 1174.653948] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1174.653951] usb 1-1.3: Product: Biometric Coprocessor
[ 1174.653954] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: UPEK
[ 1174.705043] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 112
[ 1174.928215] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 113 using ehci-pci
[ 1175.037714] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=147e, idProduct=2016
[ 1175.037721] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1175.037726] usb 1-1.3: Product: Biometric Coprocessor
[ 1175.037729] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: UPEK
[ 1175.217087] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 113
[ 1175.440140] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 114 using ehci-pci
[ 1175.557153] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=147e, idProduct=2016
[ 1175.557155] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1175.557156] usb 1-1.3: Product: Biometric Coprocessor
[ 1175.557157] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: UPEK
```

dmesg is pretty much nothing but this thing

I would really love any help on either making it work or disabling it so it isn't taking a dump all over dmesg

Comment: I have also tried echo '1-1.3' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind and it doesn't stay unbound

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this article or a similar google search would help with your situation:

[How do you edit the Blacklist.conf file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148631/how-do-you-edit-the-blacklist-conf-file)

Comment: I think blacklisting the ehci_hcd would kill all the usb devices though